# Elasticsearch ingest circle processor problem

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I'm trying to insert a location that is using a circle processor to generate the circle points. Location [30, 10] in the document is generated with the circle points properly.
docs: Circle processor | Elasticsearch Guide [8.5] | Elastic

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/polygonize_circles
{
  "description": "translate circle to polygon",
  "processors": [
    {
      "circle": {
        "field": "circle",
        "error_distance": 1,
        "shape_type": "geo_shape"
      }
    }
  ]
}


PUT circles
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "circle": {
        "type": "geo_shape"
      }
    }
  }
}
 

PUT circles/_doc/2?pipeline=polygonize_circles
{
  "circle": {
    "type": "circle",
    "radius": "40m",
    "coordinates": [35.539917, -78.472000]
  }
}

GET circles/_doc/2

But if I use another location. The generated coordinate looks like an oval with the wrong radius.

my location [35.54171753710938, -78.472]

created coordinates:
"circle": {
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  35.54171753710938,
                  -78.472
                ],
                [
                  35.54112406581135,
                  -78.47173430472324
                ],
                [
                  35.540630197847186,
                  -78.47167003953963
                ],
                [
                  35.540375564960186,
                  -78.47165140797998
                ],
                [
                  35.54021828908823,
                  -78.47164529506406
                ],
                [
                  35.54010640465818,
                  -78.47164274491611
                ],
                [
                  35.54001650261309,
                  -78.47164162397662
                ],
                [
                  35.53993651647515,
                  -78.47164003979641
                ],
                [
                  35.539858062238046,
                  -78.47164049555624
                ],
                [
                  35.53977439153409,
                  -78.47164207973975
                ],
                [
                  35.5396750942597,
                  -78.47164321572573
                ],
                [
                  35.5395458932956,
                  -78.47164846905713
                ],
                [
                  35.539348254773515,
                  -78.47165779735127
                ],
                [
                  35.53899878746994,
                  -78.47169061817682
                ],
                [
                  35.53833938849573,
                  -78.47182842440924
                ],
                [
                  35.53833938849573,
                  -78.47217157559075
                ],
                [
                  35.53899878746994,
                  -78.47230938182317
                ],
                [
                  35.539348254773515,
                  -78.47234220264872
                ],
                [
                  35.5395458932956,
                  -78.47235153094286
                ],
                [
                  35.5396750942597,
                  -78.47235678427425
                ],
                [
                  35.53977439153409,
                  -78.47235792026024
                ],
                [
                  35.539858062238046,
                  -78.47235950444374
                ],
                [
                  35.53993651647515,
                  -78.47235996020358
                ],
                [
                  35.54001650261309,
                  -78.47235837602337
                ],
                [
                  35.54010640465818,
                  -78.47235725508388
                ],
                [
                  35.54021828908823,
                  -78.47235470493592
                ],
                [
                  35.540375564960186,
                  -78.47234859202001
                ],
                [
                  35.540630197847186,
                  -78.47232996046036
                ],
                [
                  35.54112406581135,
                  -78.47226569527675
                ],
                [
                  35.54171753710938,
                  -78.472
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "type": "Polygon"
          }
```

[coordinates mapping on google maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIEjh.png)

Is it an issue or It's working as expected? Because the coordinates are not a circle so it's impacting the search result.

Comment: Are you sure that you're specifying longitude / latitude, instead of latitude / longitude ? Also it doesn't seem that your google maps shows the same coordinates as in your example

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify your coordinate array using [longitude first and then latitude](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html), I think you did the opposite and your circle is in the middle of Antartica.

If you do it like this:

```
PUT circles/_doc/2?pipeline=polygonize_circles
{
  "circle": {
    "type": "circle",
    "radius": "40m",
    "coordinates": [-78.472000, 35.539917]
  }
}
```

Then your circle doesn't look oval anymore:

[image: Circle]

From the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html):

> In GeoJSON and WKT, and therefore Elasticsearch, the correct coordinate order is longitude, latitude (X, Y) within coordinate arrays. This differs from many Geospatial APIs (e.g., Google Maps) that generally use the colloquial latitude, longitude (Y, X).

Comment: Thanks. I did as per your suggestion. But I can not use the new coordinate to test on Google Maps right? What is the map that you use in the screenshot?

Comment: I used geojson.io.... just make sure to always specify coordinate arrays as `[longitude, latitude]` and not the other way around